# angular interceptor is not rejected

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

`$resource` calls some API. If it returns some flag, than request should drop to `.catch()` section of `$resource('api/').get(...).$promise.catch();`

My interceptor does not trigger that call. It calls `.then` in any case

Interceptor code:

```
.factory('SomeHTTPInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.data.someFlag) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
})
```

How to get same response, but in catch section w/o checking for error in every single request?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the responseError handler as per doc
responseError: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.

```
.factory('SomeHTTPInterceptor', ['$q', function($q) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.data.someFlag) {
                // do something
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: As far as i understand, `responseError` get called, when previous interceptor has rejected request or it (request) has failed. So i can't do that first rejection.